# In a React application, how do I use .contains() on a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this click handler:

```
clickHandler = event => {
    if (this.node.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log("clicked inside");
        return;
    }
    console.log("clicked outside");
};
```

My List component is defined like this;

```
const List = styled.ul`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #789;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
`;
```

Then in my render function I have this;

```
<List ref={node => (this.node = node)} key={index}>
```

When my click handler is executed, I get the following error:

TypeError: _this.node.contains is not a function

If I console log this.node I can see it is a styled component, but it does not have a ref nor an innerRef property, so I don't see how I can access the underlying node element so that I can use .contains()

This is what I have in package.json:

```
"styled-components": "^3.4.5",
```

Comment: What uses the clickHandler?

Comment: Will you share some more code?

Comment: Which version of styled-components are you using?

Comment: the click handler is added to the document in componentDidMount(). As far as I can tell my code is the same as what is listed in the proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the `ref` to your styled-component, you should still be able to access the inner-node element. Below we will use the `clickHandler` as a call-back to a window event-listener.

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-surf-kivtr

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const List = styled.div`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  node = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
  }

  clickHandler = event => {
    if (this.node.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log(this.node);
      console.log("clicked inside");
      return;
    }
    console.log("clicked outside");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List ref={ref => (this.node = ref)}>
          <div>Example</div>
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between your code and mine. However, your's works and mine doesn't. Maybe I'm using different version of styled components.

Comment: ah, you're using version 4 and i'm on version 3. Maybe I should try upgrading.

Comment: @srayner ah yeah! That's probably it :). Is it alright to upgrade?